# Unable to access variable inside mongoose findone()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

For some reason I cant access the strike variable outside of the findOne fucntion. In the final callback, the strike variable comes out to be empty.

````
  clashApiClient
    .clanByTag(tag)
    .then((response) => {
      var reply = "";
      response.memberList.forEach((member) => {
        var strike = "";
        Player.findOne({ playerTAG: member.tag }, (err, player) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            callback("Error: ", err);
          }
          if (!player) {
            strike = "Strike information doesn't exist.";
          } else {
            strike = player.strikeCount + "Strikes.";
          }
        });
        reply = reply + member.name + ": " + strike + "\n";
      });
      callback("```" + response.name + " :   \n\n" + reply + "```");
    })
    .catch(() => callback("Error: Something went wrong while getting data!"));
}
````

Answer (score 0):

there are  possible cases here to explore:

1.
**Player** must be a model, not a document- an instance of a model

just like User below:

```
const User = mongoose.model('User', mongoSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

2. 

check your import/require or export statement

3.
make sure there is **playerTAG** props/object is defined in the Schema

4.
Check your database to see if **Player and playerTAG** are there

5.
console.log or check the value of **member.tag** passed to **playerTAG**

6. add await
7. 

check the error you see in the console to understand the problem

just know when the query/condition passed to Model.findOne() is not met, it returns null - that is why your **strike** value is **empty**

e.g.

```
// Find one adventure whose `country` is 'Croatia', otherwise `null`
await Adventure.findOne({ country: 'Croatia' }).exec();
```